# dh_install cannot find usr/lib/lib*.a

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, cmake, opencv

I am  trying to create a `.deb` package for openCV 3.2 for raspberry pi.

My `control` file is:

```
Source: opencv
Priority: optional
Maintainer: xxx <xxx@xx.xx>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), cmake
Standards-Version: 3.9.5
Section: libs
Homepage: <insert the upstream URL, if relevant>
#Vcs-Git: git://anonscm.debian.org/collab-maint/opencv.git
#Vcs-Browser: http://anonscm.debian.org/?p=collab-maint/opencv.git;a=summary

Package: opencv-dev
Section: libdevel
Architecture: any
Depends: opencv (= ${binary:Version}), ${misc:Depends}
Description: <insert up to 60 chars description>
 <insert long description, indented with spaces>

Package: opencv1
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: <insert up to 60 chars description>
 <insert long description, indented with spaces>
```

My `opencv1.install` is:

```
usr/lib/lib*.so.*
```

and my `rules` file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# See debhelper(7) (uncomment to enable)
# output every command that modifies files on the build system.
DH_VERBOSE = 1
export DH_OPTIONS=-v

# see EXAMPLES in dpkg-buildflags(1) and read /usr/share/dpkg/*
DPKG_EXPORT_BUILDFLAGS = 1
include /usr/share/dpkg/default.mk

# see FEATURE AREAS in dpkg-buildflags(1)
#export DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS = hardening=+all

# see ENVIRONMENT in dpkg-buildflags(1)
# package maintainers to append CFLAGS
#export DEB_CFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND  = -Wall -pedantic
# package maintainers to append LDFLAGS
#export DEB_LDFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND = -Wl,--as-needed


# main packaging script based on dh7 syntax
%:
    dh $@ --buildsystem=cmake 

# debmake generated override targets
# This is example for Cmake (See http://bugs.debian.org/641051 )
override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- \
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..

override_dh_auto_test:
```

The problem is that when I execute the following command:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc --source-option=--include-binaries --source-option=-isession
```

It configures and builds opencv but when it tries to install, it outputs the following error:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/debianizator/opencv-3.2.0/obj-arm-linux-gnueabihf'
        cd /home/pi/debianizator/opencv-3.2.0
   dh_install -O--buildsystem=cmake
        cp --reflink=auto -a debian/tmp/usr/include/opencv debian/opencv-dev//usr/include/
        cp --reflink=auto -a debian/tmp/usr/include/opencv2 debian/opencv-dev//usr/include/
dh_install: Cannot find (any matches for) "usr/lib/lib*.a" (tried in "." and "debian/tmp")
dh_install: opencv-dev missing files: usr/lib/lib*.a
dh_install: Cannot find (any matches for) "usr/share/pkgconfig/*" (tried in "." and "debian/tmp")
dh_install: opencv-dev missing files: usr/share/pkgconfig/*
dh_install: missing files, aborting
debian/rules:23: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: fallo: fakeroot debian/rules binary devolvió un estado de salida de error 2
```

It seems that doesn't find the static libraries, and in fact, if I list `tmp/lib` there aren't static libraries. This is the content of `debian/tmp/lib`

```
libopencv_calib3d.so           libopencv_objdetect.so.3.2.0
libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2       libopencv_photo.so
libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2.0     libopencv_photo.so.3.2
libopencv_core.so              libopencv_photo.so.3.2.0
libopencv_core.so.3.2          libopencv_shape.so
libopencv_core.so.3.2.0        libopencv_shape.so.3.2
libopencv_features2d.so        libopencv_shape.so.3.2.0
libopencv_features2d.so.3.2    libopencv_stitching.so
libopencv_features2d.so.3.2.0  libopencv_stitching.so.3.2
libopencv_flann.so             libopencv_stitching.so.3.2.0
libopencv_flann.so.3.2         libopencv_superres.so
libopencv_flann.so.3.2.0       libopencv_superres.so.3.2
libopencv_highgui.so           libopencv_superres.so.3.2.0
libopencv_highgui.so.3.2       libopencv_videoio.so
libopencv_highgui.so.3.2.0     libopencv_videoio.so.3.2
libopencv_imgcodecs.so         libopencv_videoio.so.3.2.0
libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2     libopencv_video.so
libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0   libopencv_video.so.3.2
libopencv_imgproc.so           libopencv_video.so.3.2.0
libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2       libopencv_videostab.so
libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2.0     libopencv_videostab.so.3.2
libopencv_ml.so                libopencv_videostab.so.3.2.0
libopencv_ml.so.3.2            pkgconfig
libopencv_ml.so.3.2.0          python2.7
libopencv_objdetect.so         python3.4
libopencv_objdetect.so.3.2
```

On the other hand I don't know why it tries to install static libraries because as I posted above the `opencv1.install` doesn't tell that static libraries must be installed.

So how can I solve this error and generate a `.deb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit `debian/opencv-dev.install` and remove references to non-existent files (at least `usr/lib/lib*a.` and `usr/share/pkg-config/*`, although the latter feels like a mistake).

Comment: Thanks you. I am watching `debian/opencv1.install` but not `debian/opencv-dev.install`